# Mongo Aggregate - Calculating based on dates

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

Here is a sample document.

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e557779ed588826d84cef11"},
"meter_id":"1001",
"date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1509474600000"}},
"parameter_name":"hvac","voltage":{"unit":"V"},
"current":{"unit":"AMP"},
"powerFactor":{"unit":"phi"},
"angle":{"unit":"degree"},
"activePower":{"unit":"kwh"},
"reactivePower":{"unit":"kwh"},
"apparentPower":{"unit":"kwh"},
"frequency":{"unit":"hz"},
"thd":{"unit":"percentage"},
"energy":{"Energy":"5.7"},
"power":{"unit":"watt"},
```

And there are around 100 000 documents. I want to filter out the documents whose date is greater than the date i specify and calculate the total energy i.e energy.Energy

I used the below aggregation, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
const endDate = new Date(12-12-2018)
 MeterData.aggregate([
      {
          $group: {
              _id: "$meter_id",
              total: { $sum: 1 },
              totalEnergy: { $sum: { $toDouble: "$energy.Energy"
                   } },
                   dateSum: {
                    $sum: {
                      $toDouble: {
                        $not: [{
                          $cond: {
                            if: {
                              $gte: [
                                "$date", endDate
                              ]
                            },
                            then: "$energy.Energy",
                            else: 0
                          }
                        }

                        ]


                    }
                    }
                   }
          }
      }
  ])
```

Comment: You should not store numeric values as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { date: { $gte: ISODate("2016-12-12") } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$meter_id",
         total: { $sum: 1 },
         totalEnergy: { $sum: "$energy.Energy" }
      }
   }
])
```

See [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KH2a5VT1xAF)

Comment: ISODate is not defined in mongo, and if i use new Date() it doesnt give expected results , is there any work around for that .?

Comment: `new Date("2016-12-12")` should also work. Or try `new Date(2018, 12, 12)`, or `new Date("2016-12-12T00:00:00Z")`